# How to filter out message from a Python app, using Logstash and Shipper?

Tags: python, logging, logstash

How to I log to Stash from a Python app? Here is my Shipper as it stands now.

I am using Redis to Shipper to the indexer which then goes to ES. But what is best practice to log from Python and only get logs from your app rather than the other sys log messages via a filter?  To

```
# This is a comment. You should use comments to describe
# parts of your configuration.
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/syslog"
    type => "syslog"
  }
}

output {
  redis { host => "<%=@redis_host%>" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}

import syslog
syslog.syslog('omg...how does logstash work?')
```

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly?  Isn't you want to shipper python logs to indexer? The best way is your write your logs to file and shipper read the log file as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but unanswered...

Set your python to log to its own application logs, and use that as your logstash input.